# CSS/Javascript fluent push menus on all devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, responsive-design

I am trying to implement menus like "Left Push Menu" here:

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/

However, the animation here is not smooth not on iPod, not on recent iPad. I wonder whether there is something wrongly implemented or whether it must be done with javascript to create smooth animation.

For instance, what works smoothly is this:

https://medium.com/

The difference is that first link moves the whole document content, the second just moves the right part, which covers the left (But I doubt it makes such a difference in animation speed). I examined the source and I can't find out whether it is done by CSS or javascript.

What is the key to making the animation smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution which works great on all platform:

```
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Moving with translate3d is smooth and fast.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it just seems like iPads/iPods are not friendly when it comes to animations/tweening.

I looked at your website on my phone, and it seemed to work great (it's an android). Personally, I wouldn't worry about it, I don't think it's that big of a deal. But if it's really bugging you..

I'm guessing you're using css3 transitions right now? You could try javascript, here's a great tutorial: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions